# How can someone not working in the pharmacologic industry help find a solution for a medical problem without donating money and without waiting?

Tags: medications

The question is about the minimum knowledge and equipment required to create

1. drugs for treating infectious diseases or
2. drugs for pain reduction or
3. drugs for cancer treatment

and where to acquire necessary knowledge and equipment.

Comment: Welcome Vitalis.  This opinion-based question could perhaps be better addressed in PhilosophySE.  Your question is full of assumptions with differing degrees of accuracy.  There are all sorts of issues you're not taking into consideration, and your question title doesn't seem to be what you're asking in teh question.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Great reply. But I have to disagree. Feel free to address the issues I am not taking into consideration and I am willing to rephrase the question.

Comment: First, your title is a potential question for HealthSE, but the body of text is not on topic for HealthSE.  This isn't a place to rant, either. And as someone who has done research and seen a ton of the pros/cons of it, there are more issues than can be discussed in this comments section.  Stack Exchange is not like other Q&A sites, check out some of the guides for more info

Comment: If your actual question is how can a person contribute without getting into the field themselves, or giving money, that might be on topic here.  But the rest of it isn't.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Good. I will ask the question the way it was somewhere else. I rephrased it here. Now, I want you to reply.

Comment: This is now a great question and an important one to discuss.  I think it's on topic but that might be up for debate.  It is broad but I think it can be reasonably answered.

Comment: One thing I want to correct based on your post before the (good) edits. The scientists who do the actual work of discovering drugs and treatments rarely drive Porsches because they are rarely wealthy. They can no more afford a pay cut than you can. Modern drugs are rarely, if ever, created by an individual or two. They are the product of hundreds of scientists and technicians, virtually none of whom are wealthy. Don't confuse scientists with pharmaceutical corporations and their executives.

Answer (score 2):

Research studies can be simple or complicated, depending on many factors including the nature of the thing that you are investigating, the history of discovery in that field (what knowledge you're working from or springboarding off of), materials required, whether it is in vivo or in vitro, whether animals or humans must be involved as test subjects, etc etc etc.

The traditional paths are going through school to get a science or medical degree of some sort.  You don't have to be a PhD or MD to do research, you can do quite a lot with an undergrad degree.  But usually the principal investigators in research studies are either PhDs or MDs.

There are ways to apply to be involved in research without a degree, as an assistant or lab technician, depending on the research.

If you can imagine how much research has been done on all 3 of those areas, you'd see that you'd need to do a lot of literature review as guidance and to inform you whether you're repeating failed experiments or going down the wrong direction, and a bunch of other things.

Outside of science, you could enter the field via public health.  Or epidemiology/statistics.

Coming completely from outside of the science field OR academic fields, and wanting to contribute is a lot less well-traveled path.  Innovators may be able to make huge leaps in research, but they still require a frame of knowledge to do so.

But if you have money, you can do a lot by supporting research proposals that you like, researchers that you like, or even opening a lab and setting your own standards - but we are talking about a ton of money there.  Note there are always regulatory bodies to ensure quality and safety that you have to follow.

Without education or money or political sway, you can get involved in professional groups (or grass roots) advocacy to improve the medical field and research.  There are efforts to try to get journals made open access rather than paid, efforts to control prescription costs, efforts to establish more open databases of information, etc.

Lastly, you could be a subject participant in clinical research trials yourself.  There are many out there seeking participants in discovering new medications.  Read about what they're studying so you know what you're contributing to.

Beyond these answers, there isn't a lot more opportunity I can come up with.  I love the enthusiasm, idealism, and concept of being able to drop in and help!  But usually for meaningful contributions in research, it usually takes quite a bit of work.  Quite a bit.

Comment: To wax philosophical a moment, there are a TON of alternative medicine treatments that need more study. Those would be cheaper than studies on new substances.  There's no huge payoff from it so pharm industry isn't chasing those down.  But you could make a huge contribution to the health field if you were to find, for example, that X herb does in fact have strong evidence in treatment of Y disease.  Like everything it would require background lit review of naturopathic/other journals first, but it's a cheaper route than synthesizing something new.  But funding is the issue, as always.

Comment: I like the idea of synthesizing. I would look at the most promising mechanisms that were found in nature and optimize them to have the desired effect. So the fundament would be compounds found in nature. I would start synthesizing compounds whose validity could be quickly checked like those glowing in the dark bacteria or synthesizing flavours. To avoid human rejection/allergic reactions I would imitate the natural compound, that does the job badly, as much as possible and then optimize using statistical models on a computer.

Comment: I saw https://www.ted.com/talks/lee_cronin_print_your_own_medicine?language=de#t-167580 and https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/jul/21/chemputer-that-prints-out-drugs - I presume when it comes to it, a computer and a desired compound is all you need nowadays to have it produced and shipped.

Comment: @DoctorWhom, this is a great answer. I'd like to add to the array of options presented here the concept of [Citizen Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_science). The platform I'm most familiar with is [Zooniverse](https://www.zooniverse.org) and they even have a [medicine section](https://www.zooniverse.org/projects?discipline=medicine&page=1&status=live). Currently there isn't anything specific to drug design, but the antibiotics project (Bash the Bug) aims directly at improving the treatment for tuberculosis. Citizen science is a great way to contribute, open virtually to anyone.

Comment: I literally had never heard of that!  It sounds amazing and something that should exist. I will look into it.